# CentOS 7 - Updating Packages Not Found in the Default Repos

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, webserver, centos7

We recently began developing an internal site using WordPress' latest available version, version 4.4. We had originally created the VM for this server using SLES 11 SP3, but found that this OS was too outdated to get the most up-to-date software to have WordPress work as expected. So we decided to switch to CentOS 7, the latest CentOS version available.

* ***EDIT:*** I actually just noticed that SLES 11 SP3 was release 10-23-2015, I guess I was thinking of 10 SP3, which is what we USED to use all the time... Maybe that SLES version was good and I just didn't have the right repos..?

We have the VM setup and CentOS 7 was installed using the DVD-ISO from CentOS' site.

I am used to SuSE's *YaST Package Manager* which made package management a breeze for the most part. But, now that it's CentOS, it looks like YUM is what I use for package management, which is a command line only tool...

The problem I am having now is that the recommended software for WordPress, which I found HERE --> https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ says I should be using these versions of the following packages:

> ```
> PHP 5.6 or greater
> MySQL 5.6 or greater
> The mod_rewrite Apache module
> ```

However, my CentOS install has the following versions of PHP, Apache and MySQL *(*I'm also not sure how to view installed Apache Modules?)*:

```
# php --version
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.44-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 19 2015 21:43:13
```

And since the *"Application Installer"* GUI program isn't really showing me anything other then non-essential programs, it's not very helpful.

Are there any CentOS repos that I can add to get those programs updated to the newest versions?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance,
Matt

Comment: Did you succeed in updating your packages ?

Comment: I ended up switching back to the original VM that we had started using which was SLES 11 SP3. Didn't realize it at the time, but that 11.3 version was a lot newer then I previously thought. And I was able to find the requisite repos from SuSE's downloads site...

Comment: Perfect , glad everything worked out!

Answer (score 1):

## Php

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502656/upgrading-php-on-centos-6-5-final)

```
# Update the repository package manager
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
# Remove last version (avoid conflicts)
yum remove php-common
# Install all the required components of version 5.6
yum install php56w
yum install php56w-mysql
yum install php56w-common
yum install php56w-pdo
yum install php56w-opcache
```

---

## Apache

[Source](http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-apache/)

For the apache rewrite module, first of all, check if it exists as a module

```
ls /etc/httpd/modules | grep mod_rewrite
```

if it outputs `mod_rewrite.so` , it's because the module exists. Next thing to do is to check if the module is loaded.

```
grep -i LoadModule /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep rewrite
```

It should outputs something like this :

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

- Means  that the module is loaded

OR

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Means that the module is not loaded, edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and remove the `#` at the beginning of the line. Then restart apache2 service:

`sudo /sbin/service httpd restart`

If the line does not exists, just add it in the httpd.conf file :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Last thing to do is to check if AllowOverride is activated. Type the following command :

```
grep -i AllowOverride /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

If it outputs `AllowOverride None` , change it for `AllowOverride All` in the httpd.conf file (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`)

---

Hope it helped :).