# how to update php 5.3 to 5.4 in centos 6 without error?

Tags: php

from the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502656/upgrading-php-on-centos-6-5-final) ,I use remi repo to `yum update php*` to version 5.4
but get:
 `--> Finished Dependency Resolution

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Removing: php-common-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Updated By: php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Removing: php-pdo-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64 (@updates)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8
           Updated By: php-pdo-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.3.3-47.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.3.3-47.el6
           Available: php-pdo-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi

 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

`

I don't know what's the problem, thanks for any help!

Comment: You yum repo have different php version:  like  this: Available: php-pdo-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-13.el6.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
>
> Updated By: php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-test)

Disable "remi-test" (excepted if you want to test unstable packages, but in this case, you need, at least php 5.6, in "remi-php56")

Comment: collect , I am using mysql5.7.Disabled remi-test,still get Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.53-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.i686 (base)
               Not found

Comment: You have to switch to php-mysqlnd, instead of php-mysql, which don't have any dependency on libmysqlclient, or use compat-mysql55 (better way is to use "remi-php54" instead of "remi", and in all case, never "remi-test")

Comment: Please also remind that PHP 5.4 is EOL, even if packages in "remi-php54" repository have some security backports, so you should really consider using any PHP version > 5.6.

Comment: rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm has no remi-php54, could you tell me how to get it?

Comment: It have it: $ rpm -qf /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php54.repo => remi-release-6.8-2.el6.remi.noarch (perhaps need to update remi-release first)