# Unable to update PHP from 5.4 to higher version in CentOs 7

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

I'm using `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)` and for some of my project tasks i need PHP higher than 5.4 but unable to update it.
i used these commands:

`rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm`

`rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm`

and then:

`yum install php56w php56w-opcache`

as described [HERE](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/)

but getting this error:

> Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64
> Error: Package: php56w-5.6.32-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
> Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
> Installed: httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64 (@updates)
> httpd-mmn = 20120211
> httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
> httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
> Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.x86_64 (base)
> httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
> httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
> httpd-mmn = 20120211
> Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.2.x86_64 (updates)
> httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
> httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
> httpd-mmn = 20120211
> Available: httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.5.x86_64 (updates)
> httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
> httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
> httpd-mmn = 20120211
> Error: Package: php56w-common-5.6.32-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
> Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

what can i do now for updating it?

Comment: `sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common`, remove the existing php installation, and then install using your command.

Comment: i also try removing `php-common` as described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24351302/5894421) but got same issue

Comment: Are you trying to use centos6 repos in centos7?

Comment: Try repos https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/latest.rpm and https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm (7 instead of 6), firstly remove these.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [How to update Apache to 2.4.29 using SCL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412171/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). It covers Python, Apache and PHP. You should be able to leave MariaDB at 5.5.

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman, that did the trick for me!

Comment: Glad to help @KevinY

Answer (score 0):

To install, first you must add the Webtatic EL yum repository information corresponding to your CentOS 7.x version to yum:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

Than execute yum install:

```
yum install php70w php70w-mysql php70w-common php70w-xml php70w-mbstring
```